# when scraping my program halts because unique=True and won't scrape the non duplicates

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a function that scrapes and saves posts to my database.

```
def scrape_and_store_world():
  url = 'http://www.example.org'
  html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
  titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:9]
  entries = [{'href': url + box.a.get('href'),
            'src': box.img.get('src'),
            'text': box.strong.a.text,
            } for box in titles]

  for entry in entries:
      post = Post()
      post.title = entry['text']
      post.image_url = entry['src']
      post.status = 'published'
      post.save()
  return entries
```

it will scrape the latest 9 posts, but if I run it again it will cause issues telling me that a post already exist and it will stop scraping. I want to scrape the newest one and just skip over the would be duplicates without my program halting. What's the proper syntax to do that

EDIT: The Error message I get

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "blog_post_title_adf2f203_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (title)=(Nightclub On Wheels: NYC Uber Driver Puts On A Party For His Passengers!) already exists.
```

my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

STATUS_CHOICES = (
   ('draft', 'Draft'),
   ('published', 'Published'),
)
title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
```

my view.py

```
def noindex(request):
   scrape_and_store_world()
   template = "blog/post/noindex.html"
   context = {

   }
   return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: It's difficult to help you because we cannot try out your example as it is, and you did not post the full traceback.

Comment: @Chris I added more info. Do I need anything else?

Comment: You're being down voted because of what I said in the first comment.  If we can't run your code on our own machine, or the error isn't very obvious, it's almost impossible for us to divine the answer for you.

Comment: @Chris I added more content and if that's the issue then why not just say that, instead of downvoting not everything is apparent to a novice. I cant even ask questions any more. I've been told I put to much and get downvoted or I put to less and get downvoted. The fate of my vote is based on who sees it and their mood not by an actual standard set by stack. I've seen questions poorly structured and bordering silly and they have 100's of upvotes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Read this, and ensure your questions meet all the criteria and your questions will stop being downvoted.

Comment: @Chris what else needs to be provided? I have the function and unique=True obviously refers to a model. After You said add more info I did so what's the reason for the downvotes. None. Thats all the information right there. To downvote me for that is to a petty follower

Comment: downvoting gamifies and actually detracts from helping and turns into a snowball effect ofnegativity. I had to wait to get this back today and now it's off. that's why I'm pissed

Comment: novices get crushed on here. People tell you theres no such things as stupid questions when your learning and you come on here see otherwise. Novices don't always know where they are wrong and. I guess that's how they keep there returning users high

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out all I had to do was ad an if statement that queries the database to see if there is a matching title and if not then save. heres my code.

```
def scrape_and_store_world():
  url = 'http://www.worldstarhiphop.com'
  html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
  titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:9]
  entries = [{'href': url + box.a.get('href'),
              'src': box.img.get('src'),
              'text': box.strong.a.text,
              } for box in titles]

  entries = entries.__reversed__()

  for entry in entries:
      post = Post()
      post.title = entry['text']
      title = post.title
      if not Post.objects.filter(title=title):
          post.title = entry['text']
          post.body = entry['href']
          post.image_url = entry['src']
          post.status = 'published'
          post.save()

  return entries
```

I hope that this helps someone